# How to add/excecute and eventually remove new code to a program on runtime in C#

Tags: c#, runtime

What I'm trying to achieve is difficult to explain, but I will try it using a specific example.

I would like to have a program that executes some queries to my database every X amount of time (in my particular case, I am using `Jobs` by implementing `Quartz` in order to schedule the execution of all the queries). Right now, I know which queries I want to execute, but I would like to allow new queries executions in the future. Moreover, I would like these executions to be done without stopping the program.

A solution I was thinking was to implement a kind of "Listener". First of all, have a Main program that schedules a simple Job. This `Job` access a list of implemented interfaces and for each of them runs the "`Execute`" method. Every time I would like to create a new query to my database, without stopping the Main program, I would create the execution code in classes in a new project, each of them implementing an interface with the `Execute()` method, writing the code in order to execute the SQL. And later, being able to (in some way) "register" these kinds of “listeners” to a list which the Main program can access and execute their methods, without stopping the Main program.

Furthermore, I would be interested on "unregistering" the ones I don't want to execute anymore.

Here is some code about the SQL I need to execute:

On my `Program.class`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler Scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        Scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = null;
        ITrigger trigger = null;

        job = JobBuilder.Create<DBMapperJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job_DBMapper_manager", "grupo_DBMapper")
                    .Build();

        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .StartNow()
                   .WithIdentity("job_DBMapper_manager", "grupo_DBMapper")
                   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                       .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                       .RepeatForever())
                   .Build();

        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The `Job` that is scheduled:

```
private class DBMapperJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {          
        ExecuteSQL();
    }
}
```

Example of the method that executes the SQL:

```
private static void ExecuteSQL()
{    
    DbProviderFactory ibmFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("IBM.Data.DB2");
    using (DbConnection ibmConnection = ibmFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        ibmConnection.ConnectionString = ibmConnectionString;
        ibmConnection.Open();

        using (DbCommand command = ibmConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = select_sql_string

            using(IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //in many cases I need to analyze the results and store the data in objects in order to make more queries to the database.
                ...
            }
        }

        ibmConnection.Close();

        //Later I process the data
        ...
    }


    DbProviderFactory pgeFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Npgsql");
    using (var pgeConnection = pgeFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        pgeConnection.ConnectionString = pgeConnectionString;
        pgeConnection.Open();
        using (var command = pgeConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = truncate_sql_string;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        foreach (objects_processed_list)
        {
            using (var command = pgeConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "insert_sql_string";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        pgeConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Any help to achieve this or any other solution you can think about in order to solve this problem I would be really grateful. Thank you in advice for your help!

Comment: this is a bit broad, you should at least share some details (as actual code) how the queries are beeing executed

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do, but it seems to me that your approach might be from the wrong end.  Have you considered stored procedures, with a single "central" procedure that calls them?  You can change those without recompiling your application rather easily.

Comment: If you allow any statement, why not just read some text with an SQL statement inside?

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for your comments. I forgot an important detail, which I will add to the question, is that what my project has to do is to migrate data from one database to another. In some cases, only the SQL string is not enough and support classes are required (that's why only the SQL string is not enough). I can post some code as well

Comment: It sounds like you try to achieve some form of plugin functionality. You can do this (e.g.) by utilizing application domains (in order to be able to unload plugins) and AppDomain.DoCallBack - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 in order to be able to call your Execute() method.

Comment: @Jan mm that might make the trick. I will definitely take a look at it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jan for showing me the first steps to solve the problem.

Solution: use `AppDomain` (to load Assemblies by reflection), an Interface (to make the plugins talk the same language) and Quartz (to schedule the SQL executions). Here is how it works:

3 projects: the manager, one that holds the interface definition and the one that has classes that implement the interface (and would execute my SQL).

The interface definition project has the next interface:

```
public interface IJobExecution
{
    void SqlExecute();
}
```

The project that holds the classes that would execute my SQL:

```
[Serializable]
public class Ejecucion2 : MarshalByRefObject, IJobExecution
{
    public void SqlExecute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here I execute the SQL");
    }
}
```

The Manager project would have the execution program that periodically start the process to execute the method defined in the interface:

```
class Program
{
    private static IScheduler _scheduler;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        ISchedulerListener schedListener = new SchedulerListener();
        _scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.ListenerManager.AddSchedulerListener(schedListener);
        _scheduler.Start();

        UpdateJobs();

        string option = "";

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Update Jobs");
            option = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (option)
            {
                case "1":
                    UpdateJobs();
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void UpdateJobs()
    {
        //Delete old jobs
        foreach (String groupName in _scheduler.GetJobGroupNames())
        {
            foreach (JobKey newJobKey in _scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(groupName)))
            {
                _scheduler.DeleteJob(newJobKey);
            }
        }

        //Create new jobs
        List<Tuple<string, string>> pathsNamesDll = GetDllPathsAndNames();

        int jobNr = 1;
        foreach (Tuple<string,string> dllPathName in pathsNamesDll)
        {
            try
            {
                IJobDetail job = null;
                ITrigger trigger = null;

                job = JobBuilder.Create<MapperJob>()
                            .WithIdentity("Job_" + jobNr, "Group_" + jobNr)
                            .UsingJobData("DLL_NAME", dllPathName.Item2)
                            .UsingJobData("DLL_PATH", dllPathName.Item1)
                            .Build();

                trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                       .WithIdentity("Job_" + jobNr, "Group_" + jobNr)
                       .StartAt(DateTime.Now) //To make the example easy I define all the start time to "Now"...
                       .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                           .WithIntervalInHours(24)//... and execute the Job every day.
                           .RepeatForever())
                       .Build();

                _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                jobNr++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Tuple<string, string>> GetDllPathsAndNames()
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> pathsNamesDll = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        //Here I fill the list getting the Dll Paths and the Class Names that implement the IJobExecution from an XML or some other way
        return pathsNamesDll;
    }
}    

public class MapperJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        string dllPath = dataMap.GetString("DLL_PATH");
        string dllName = dataMap.GetString("DLL_NAME");
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(key.Name + "_" + key.Group + "_Execution_Domain");
        try
        {
            IJobExecution myObject = (IJobExecution)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(dllPath, dllName);
            myObject.SqlExecute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }
    }
}
```

With this solution I can:

1- Update the DLL that holds the classes that would execute my SQL and its changes will be automatically updated in the Manager Project program. Since I do an `AppDomain.Unload(domain);` if the program is not executing any of that dll classes at that time, I can update the dll without the need of stopping the Manager Program. If it's working by that time, I just have to wait until it finishes and I can later update the dll.

2- Adding a new SQL execution by adding a new DLL to the XML file that I'm reading in `GetDllPathsAndNames()` method and choosing the option "1 - Update Jobs" from the menu to reload all the DLLs without stopping the Manager program.

3- Remove an existing SQL execution by deleting the DLL from the XML file and choosing the option "1 - Update Jobs" from the menu to update the DLLs without stopping the Manager program.

With some small changes you can make this solution more robust, but I didn't want to write a very complex example for the solution.